# Why can I not overload this base class method?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, multiple-inheritance

So, I have a base class:

```
enum ComparableType
{
    CompType_ShaderObject
};

class Comparable 
{
public:
    Comparable( void ) {};
    Comparable( ComparableType ct ) : mComparableType( ct )
    {}
    inline virtual std::string& getKey( void ) = 0;
    virtual ComparableType getType( void ) = 0;  
protected:
    virtual ~Comparable( void ){ } ;
protected:
    virtual bool operator>( const Comparable& isLessThan ) = 0;
    virtual bool operator<( const Comparable& isGreaterThan ) = 0;
    virtual bool operator>=( const Comparable& isLessThanOrEqualTo ) = 0;
    virtual bool operator<=( const Comparable& isGreaterThanOrEqualTo ) = 0;
    virtual bool operator==( const Comparable& isEqualTo ) = 0;
    virtual bool operator!=( const Comparable& isNotEqualTo ) = 0;

protected:
   ComparableType mComparableType;

};
```

Which acts as a base for the following:

```
class ShaderComparable : public Comparable, public std::string
    {
    public:
        ShaderComparable( void ) { };
        ShaderComparable( const char* shaderFilename );
        ~ShaderComparable( void );

    public:
        inline std::string& getKey( void ) { return mFilename; } 
        inline ComparableType getType( void ) { return mComparableType; }

    public:
        virtual bool operator>( const ShaderComparable& isLessThan );
        virtual bool operator<( const ShaderComparable& isGreaterThan );
        virtual bool operator>=( const ShaderComparable& isLessThanOrEqualTo );
        virtual bool operator<=( const ShaderComparable& isGreaterThanOrEqualTo );
        virtual bool operator==( const ShaderComparable& isEqualTo );
        virtual bool operator!=( const ShaderComparable& isNotEqualTo );
    private:
        inline bool isSameType( const ShaderComparable& objectToCheck ) { return mComparableType == CompType_ShaderObject; }
        std::string mFilename;
    };
```

The only problem is that, for some reason, I'm unable to overload the operator functions from the base class to accept the type of `ShaderComparable`, as opposed to just `Comparable`. Is there a way around this?

My errors are as follows:

```
>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(26): error C2653: 'ShaderComparable' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(26): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(33): error C2653: 'ShaderComparable' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(33): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(33): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(39): error C2653: 'ShaderComparable' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(39): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(39): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(44): error C2653: 'ShaderComparable' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(44): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(44): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(49): error C2653: 'ShaderComparable' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(49): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\shadercomparable.cpp(49): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
```

**Update**

Here is the source file it is coming from:

```
ShaderComparable::ShaderComparable( const char* shaderFilename ) 
        :   Comparable( CompType_ShaderObject ),
            mFilename( shaderFilename ) 
    {}

    ShaderComparable::~ShaderComparable( void )
    {
    }

    bool ShaderComparable::operator>( const ShaderComparable& isLessThan ) 
    {
        std::string toCompare = std::string();

        if( toCompare.compare( mFilename ) > 0 )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool ShaderComparable::operator<( const ShaderComparable& isGreaterThan ) 
    {

        std::string toCompare = std::string();
        return true;
    }

    bool ShaderComparable::operator>=( const ShaderComparable& isLessThanOrEqualTo ) 
    {

        return false;
    }

    bool ShaderComparable::operator<=( const ShaderComparable& isGreaterThanOrEqualTo ) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool ShaderComparable::operator==( const ShaderComparable& isEqualTo ) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool ShaderComparable::operator!=( const ShaderComparable& isNotEqualTo ) 
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: compiles just fine - http://ideone.com/vse9u

Comment: Two things... the function signatures of your comparison operators do not match between base and derived classes.  This will result in things not working like you'd expect.  Secondly, do not derive from the standard library containers (std::string in this case).  Their destructors are not virtual, so your derived class will leak when they're destroyed.

Comment: @luke no, it's UB. You don't know they'll leak.

Comment: @luke Is there a way to differentiate from the comparison operators in the base and derived?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore my mistake, but he still shouldn't be deriving from std::string :)

Comment: @luke good point but the destructor issue would only matter for `std::string* s = new ShaderComparable`

Comment: @Holland because the code compiles.

Comment: @luke. (from Mr Pedantic this morning) They will only leak if destroyed via delete on a pointer to std::string. Static/Automatic and deleting pointers (of type ComparableType* (or derived pointer)) will correctly be destroyed.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore

Well, it certainly doesn't on my system. I'll post my sourcefile.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore does the code still compile if you instantiate a ShaderComparable (as he is surely doing)?  I would guess not because he's not supplying implementations of the pure virtual functions from the base class.  The function signatures need to match.

Comment: Why does the base class operator functions take pointer references while the derived class operator functions take references?

Comment: That was a mistake I made. *Fixed.

Comment: @Holland the function signatures for your comparisons still don't match.  You're essentially trying to do this: http://ideone.com/zy40M which won't work.

Comment: Extending @LokiAstari's comment: a derived class that is to be used polymorphically and inherits multiple base classes can be problematic - notably when the *destructors* of those base classes are not consistent, virtually.

Comment: Are you including SharedComparable.h in the file you're implementing the functions?

Comment: @Luchican:  I suspect that IDEONE is non-compliant here.  Perhaps some compiler options?

Comment: As Holland claims he has found the problem and says nothing more, I think it's time to close question. Just flip coin to choose between 'too localized' and 'not a real question'.

Comment: @JohnDibling it's not non-compliant. There's nothing "illegal" with that code. When you try to instantiate a `ShaderComparable`, you get the(expected) errors claiming that there are several pure-virtual functions that haven't been implemented, but that doesn't make it illegal.

Comment: Do not inherit from `std::string`! You will cause trouble if you add any state to the derived class. Use composition if you must extend STL.

Comment: Could be time for chat room. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only problem is that, for some reason, I'm unable to overload the
>   operator functions from the base class to accept the type of
>   ShaderComparable, as opposed to just Comparable. Is there a way around
>   this?

You cannot "overload" virtual functions this way.  The derived class (or one of its subclasses) must implement all of the pure virtual functions, and that requires that the arguments exactly match.

What you can do is use [dynamic_cast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast):

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo(A&) = 0;
};

struct B : public A
{
    virtual void foo(A& myA)
    {
        try
        {
            B& myB = dynamic_cast<B&>(myA);  // dynamic_cast is what you want, but be aware it has runtime overhead
            // do something 'B' specific, with myB
        }
        catch (const std::bad_cast& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "This object is not of type B" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: If he's got control of both the base `Comparable` class and the things derived from it, this could also be a candidate for double-dispatch

Answer (score 1):

When you implement final overrider, the parameter list must be identical to the base class.  Yours is not.  Here is a simplified example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual Base& foo(const Base& obj) = 0;
};

class Der : public Base
{
public:
    void Base& foo(const Der& obj)
    {
      return * this;
    };
};

int main () {
    Base* p = new Der;

    return 0;

}
```

This code is not legal because `Der::foo()` takes a `Der` reference as a parameter, not a `Base` reference.  This is legal:

```
class Der : public Base
{
public:
    void Base& foo(const Base& obj)
    {
      return * this;
    };
};
```

As an aside, even though the parameter list must be identical to the base class declaration, the return type need not be identical.  It must, however, be co-variant.  So, this is also legal:

```
class Der : public Base
{
public:
    void Der& foo(const Base& obj)
    {
      return * this;
    };
};
```